# How to use a zod field has different validation based on conditions

Tags: typescript, rest, types, zod

We are working a project where we share types between front end and back end. Some of the fields are **mongodb.bson.ObjectId** type. Is there a way to selectively validate in the same type file such that they are treated like **ObjectId** on the backend but as **String** on the front end. The code of the type is as follows:

```
import { z } from "zod";
import { ObjectId } from "bson";

export const AITypeObjectIdTransform = z.custom<ObjectId>().transform(value => new ObjectId(value));
export type AITypeObjectIdTransform = z.infer<typeof AITypeObjectIdTransform>;

export const BaseObject = z.object({
  _id: AITypeObjectIdTransform.optional(),
});
```

We want _id to be treated as AITypeObjectIdTransform.optional() on backend and zod.string().optional() on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.merge`](https://zod.dev/?id=merge) method,

> If the two schemas share keys, the properties of B overrides the property of A. The returned schema also inherits the "unknownKeys" policy (strip/strict/passthrough) and the catchall schema of B.

```
export const BaseObject = z.object({
  _id: AITypeObjectIdTransform.optional(),
});

export const BaseObjectFrontend = BaseObject.merge(z.object({
  _id: z.string().optional(),
}));
```

As you can see from the screenshot, the types are correct. If you have additional properties, they'll stay as they are, without needing to copy them.

[image: the code above with z.infer showing the types]

TypeScript Playground: https://tsplay.dev/w6GzRN

If for some reason you need the same variable to have both types, you'll need an environment variable or similar to control its value, such as

```
export const BaseObject = z.object({
  _id: (process.env.FRONTEND ? z.string() : AITypeObjectIdTransform).optional(),
});
```

but this will mess up your TypeScript types.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. An issue that we are facing is that ObjectId, can be nested in the object at any level. So the merge is not a viable solution, especially given the propensity of having nested zod objects as types.

The issue with conditional, is as you had mentioned that it will mess up typescript.

So we ended up using ObjectId everywhere. It does increase the frontend bundle size a little bit due to bson, but otherwise works perfectly well.